# What is the size of a given char?

Tags: c

I've got a code that i cannot understand in C;
char c is string, that supposed to be randomized,
here is the question however, 26 is supposed to be range of values starting from 97, but it easy to understand for integer, but in case of char i have no clue what it is supposed to be

```
char c = (char) rand() % 26 + 97;
```

Comment: If your question is about c, please tag it c, not c#

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is generating a random character. [In ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/), alphabetical characters start at 97. So, the code is taking 97, adding a random number between 0 and 25 to it, then casting it to a `char`, which generates a random alphabetical character.

Comment: I've got it now, it generates random decimal value of a single character using ASCII table. Much appreciated!

Comment: Minor: `rand() % 26` --> random number between 0 and 25 (inclusive).

Comment: It is unlikely that ASCII libraries are used; more likely, Windows-1252 (or equiv) or UTF-8. For A-Z, the values are the same, but it's important to know which character set and encoding one is using and it is almost certainly not ASCII.

Answer (score 2):

97 = ascii 'a'

It generates a random character between `'a'` and `'z'` inclusive.

Ref: [ASCII values](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Answer (score 1):

It's a bad, non-portable way to generate a random character by directly computing the [ASCII code](http://www.asciitable.com/).

A better, more portable, way is to randomize the index into a table of characters. This pushes the responsibility for what code is used to represent each character into the compiler, where it belongs:

```
char random_char(void)
{
  const char alpha[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

  return alpha[rand() % sizeof alpha];
}
```

Any decent compiler will very likely inline the above.

**NOTE** Using `%` to range-limit the return value of `rand()` is generally frowned upon, but that's not the focus here.

Comment: Would `static` be useful here as in `static const char alpha[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";`?

Comment: @chux It would of course work, but I don't think it adds much benefit in practice. `static` signals "I want this variable to keep its value between invocations", but here the value is `const` so it's kind of moot. I expect the compiler to *implement* it by moving it to the data segment, there shouldn't be any initialization overhead or such. Using `static` then feels like premature optimization and overcomplicating things, to me. I might be wrong, haven't read compiler output for this case lately.